# Asp.Net Core MVC How to transfer ModelState via RediretToAction?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to redirect my signIn Post methode back to the index page (Index Page has login and register form on in) but with the modelstate so i can show the errors if the sign in failed.

I have Read multiple articles about this but they either are outdate or not for asp.net core. I can't find a solution. I have tried to store the ViewData or ModelState in TempData but that doesn't work.

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           //How to access have the modelstate from SignIn here?

            return View();
        }


        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SignInModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              ....
              return RedirectToAction("","");
            }

            // here i need to save the modelstate

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pass `ModelState` as it is, ASP.NET will override it. But you can pass anything else. You index method has to support the state as a parameter:

```
public IActionResult Index(bool? IsValidAuth = null)
{
    if(IsValidAuth!=true) {} // do something
}
```

Then you can pass the state in the second parameter of `RedirectToAction`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SignInModel model)
{
    // ...
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new {IsValidAuth = false});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess with this approach the asp-validation-for Tag won't  work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your ModelState Validation error on TempData and will able to get it on your login method to show this error

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject signmanager as service in configure to login

```
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
                    model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
```

This will handel the user sign process through your application.